# Read whatsapp api cloud messages without a webhook

Tags: api, cloud, whatsapp

I'm starting to learn how to use the new whatsapp cloud api (and api web services in general), I successfuly tested the provided glitch application, but and I would like to know if the webhook is strictly necessary, I mean, I know is used to configure automatic behaviours and responses, but is there a way to read received messages without a webhook? perhaps with a GET request to a certain URL?

Answer (score 0):

actually no that's the only where to get updates and messages to your server, you'd have to subscribe to the webhook events. this is according to the cloud API documentation